# Porting from ODP.NET to dotConnect - what's the equivalent of the OracleParameter.CollectionType property?

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, devart, dotconnect

I'm porting a bunch of code from the ODP.NET drivers to DevArt dotConnect for Oracle.  I ran into the following code that no longer compiles:

```
OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter("state", OracleDbType.Number);
parameter.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray; //Red Squiggly
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.Value = State.ToArray();
parameter.Size = State.Count;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

It seems `Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter` doesn't have a CollectionType property.  What should I be using here instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20742&view=next&sid=65181f6191ad5e6388ef2c774633fe62):

> `Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter` does not have the `CollectionType`
>   property. If you set the
>   `Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter.ArrayLength`, then this parameter
>   will be PL/SQL AssociativeArray (PL/SQL Table). For more details
>   please refer
>   http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?PlSqlTable.html

In short: just set `ArrayLength` and Devart treats it automatically as `PLSQLAssociativeArray`

Your code should thus be:

```
OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "state";
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Number; 
parameter.ArrayLength = State.Count;
parameter.Value = State.ToArray();
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```